# Too many rerednders error by trying to show a FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setstate

I am trying to display a flatList of numbers like this : [(image of what the flat list would look like)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJMIN.png)
To do that I did an array of objects with a numberName and a key, it's generating with a loop:

```
const number = 5;

let [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([]);

let nums = [];
for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
nums.push({ numberName: i, key: i });

console.log(nums)
}
setNumbers((numbers) => [...numbers, ...nums]);
```

I dont think the problem is in the loop, but react is recalling the loop without showing the component. This makes an infinite loop and I have the too Many rerender error.

Here is what console.log(nums) shows [(screenshot of the console)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjP9p.png)

and here is how i am trying to render the array :

```
if(!fontsLoaded) {return <AppLoading />} 
else {return (
    <View>
        <FlatList
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            horizontal={true}
            data={numbers} //la data qu'on va afficher
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <Text style={styles.number}>{item.numberName}</Text>
            )} //la fonction qu'il va rendre
        />
    </View>
)}
```

Why do I have the too many rerenders error and how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=>{
const nums = numbers.map((value,index)=> {numberName: index,key: index})
setNumbers([...numbers, ...nums])
},[])
```

You need to do assignment/state-related stuff inside **useEffect** hook.

Answer (score 0):

For taking in account changes in states, you'll need to make it with `useState` hook, like this:

```js
    const number = props.numberProp;

    let [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {    
    let nums = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < number + 100; i++) {
        nums.push({ numberName: i, key: i });
        }
    setNumbers((numbers) => [...numbers, ...nums]);
    }, [])
```